# Is there any benefit to doing Mia's tape?

Tags: resident-evil-7

I'm on my 2nd playthrough, this time on Madhouse difficulty, and I'm wondering if it's worth bothering to do the tape labeled "Mia"

> For example, I know if you do the first tape (which you might have to do anyway to find the lever in the fireplace... not sure), you can find a lockpick near the cameraman and then pick a lock in the kitchen, which makes it unlocked for Ethan later.

The first time I did that tape I don't remember it being necessary for progression or allowing me to get extra items, but maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to watch the "Mia" videotape at all. Other than providing a bit of back-story, and teaching you about the shadow plinth puzzle (which isn't exactly hard to figure out anyway), there isn't any benefit.

That said, there are 2 trophies tied to the "Mia" videotape. That may be something to take into consideration, although certainly doesn't affect the gameplay.

Regarding your mention of the first tape in the guest house, this isn't required either. I didn't watch this at all on my first playthrough and other than the benefit you already mentioned, it doesn't prevent you progressing the game.